# Sharing a "public link" to a table in Google Fusion

Tags: google, google-drive, sharing

When I press the `Grab Link` button (beside Share button) in Fusion tables, it gives me a link.

http://screenshoot.me/nEAt0B

However when I give my friend that link, it says that he does not have permission to view the table.

What's going on here?

How do we get a "public link" to the document that anyone **with that link** can view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To make a table public, click the Share button and select the Public radio button under Visibility options. The change will be applied immediately. Close the dialog box.
>
> When the Visibility is Public, no authentication is required to view your table and visualizations embedded elsewhere can draw from your data table instantly. Access to query your data table through the API (read-only, no authentication) is also supported. Your table will be included in the Fusion Tables public table search, and may also be indexed for search engines such as Google.com.

From [Google Fusion Tables Help](http://www.google.com/support/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?answer=171221).

Comment: Thnks for the edit Alex, as was not able to do it because posted from my cell phone :-)

Comment: No No I mean I want it to be visible only to people with that link

Comment: Ok, so you want it for specific people to view it.

Comment: Yes but without the hassle of inviting them, having them accept, etc. Basically, I'd give a link and they can click access it simple and sweet